# Who is Mantramaheśvara mentioned in Shiva Sutras by Jaideva Singh?

Tags: shiva, tantra, kashmiri-shaivism

In Shiva Sutras, section III, Sutra 7, Shiva says what happens when conquering moha/mãyã:

> मोहजयादनन्ताभोगात्सहजविद्याजयः ॥ ७ ॥
> "By an all pervasive conquest of delusive Maya is there mastery of the natural, inherent knowledge of Reality.”

Further in commentary section, Jaideva Singh ji adds up reference of Svacchanda Tantra,

> As has been said in Svacchanda itself,

> "Therefore abandoning merely pure consciousness or merely inherence in Self (ätma-vyäpti) (as the aim), one should attach oneself to vidya tattva. This vidya tattva should be known as unmanā. Manas is only a notion in the heart. Such a kind of knowledge is only gradual, proceeding step by step, by degrees while unmana is knowledge in one sweep and perennial. e there is no other vidya (knowledge) like this, therefore is it the highest **vidya (*)**. By this knowledge one attains the highest Because qualities like omniscience, etc. simultaneously. It is called Vidya, because it brings about the investigation of the beginning- less characteristic of Siva, viz., Svätantrya-Sakti, because it brings about the knowledge of the Highest Self and because it dispels all that is not the Highest Self. Established in that (unmana), one can manifest the highest light (light of conscious- ness-cit-jyoti) the highest cause (i.e. Highest Siva the source of all manifestation) (IV, 393-397).

To explain it further,he adds up in note:

> **(*)** Ksemarája in his commentary on this vidya in Svacchanda Tantra warns that this vidya tattva should not be confused with the vidya tattva which includes the experients from Vijñánakala,  upto **Mantramaheśvara**. This vidya tattva is different. It is unmanã identified with Siva-consciousness.

Who is Mantramaheśvara mentioned here? At which stage of manifestation he is identified?

Comment: I'm not sure, and I may be misinterpreting the text completely- but I don't think that Mantramaheśvara is a person. I think that it is instead the name of a stage/level of consciousness/enlightenment. See [this](https://www.google.com/books/edition/%C5%9Aaiv%C4%81gamas/vEKkuLQUza8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Mantramahe%C5%9Bvara&pg=PA147&printsec=frontcover), and [this](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Wiley_Blackwell_Companion_to_Hinduis/n79vEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Mantramahe%C5%9Bvara&pg=PT623&printsec=frontcover). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @CDR At all stages Shiva only manifests himself into different tattvas. So yeah you're right too.

Answer (score 0):

[image: An idea of the realms, powers and limitations in Saiva doctrine]

There may not be exact correspondence between the terms in the above diagram and text below. The defects mentioned below are similar to limitations above. Diagram to avoid complete abstract discussion.

Vijnankala has only the defect of the anu illusion. Free of this is only Siva.
The Śaiva Śāstra, speaks of three classes of Paśu, namely, Sakala bound by the three Pāśas, Anu, Bheda, Karma, that is, limited knowledge, the seeing of the one Self, as many by the operation of Māyā, and action and its product. These are the three impurities (Mala) called Ānavamala, Māyāmala, and Kārmamala. The Sakala Jīva or Paśu is bound by all three, the Pralayākala by the first and last, and the Vijñānākala by the first only. He who is wholly freed of the remaining impurity of Anu is Śiva Himself.
Upto Mantramaheshwara means the ultimate is mantramaheshwara so should be identical or merged with Siva.